# kik.metrics.enableGoogleAnalytics() not longer working properly

Tags: kik

I have implemented kik.metrics.enableGoogleAnalytics(); on my kik page and confirmed in my google analytics that "kikSend" and "kikReceive" were in fact pinging my GA account. However, in some recent tests I found those pings appear to be very sporadic and I'm not sure why. 
- I have my universal GA script in my header along with my account/domain info
- the kik.metrics.enableGoogleAnalytics(); is in my script at the bottom
- I can successfully send a kik item to a friend
- my friend can successfully receive the item

But most of the time my GA account is not receiving the pings for those kikSend and kikReceieve events. Very possible that I am misunderstanding when those events are to be fired...I believe the kikSend should be fired any time that I successfully send a kik message to a friend. And the kikReceive should be fired every time the friend views the message. Accurate?

In the head tag:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'mydomain.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

In my script tag at the bottom (just after the app.js include...this is the first thing called:

```
<script>
kik.metrics.enableGoogleAnalytics();
</script>
```

Comment: `ga.js` doesn't fire any events unless running on the specified domain (`mydomain.com`). Are you running on a local version of your app?

Comment: thanks for the response...the "mydomain.com" was just a placeholder I used on this posting. But it is in fact my actual domain of where my kik page is hosted. Also, not sure if it matters, but I am referencing the newer analytics.js vs. ga.js. According to the kik dev docs, they default to the use of analytics.js so I think it's all good there. And I successfully get any of my custom ga event pings that I have for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

oh my...just found out that I had a huge oversight in the GA interface. The kik.metrics. enableGoogleAnalytics() works just fine. User error on my part: My real-time view was set to "Viewing: Active Users" instead of "Viewing: Events (Last 30 min)". When the "Last 30 min" was selected, that does in fact tally up the events as expected.